# Spring 4 and Apache tiles css resources not load in jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, resources, tiles

I create simple applications using Spring4, tiles3. And I have problem with resources in jsp template.

[Project Structure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzyXl.png)

Web.xml:

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/config/root-context.xml</param-value></context-param><listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener> <servlet>
<servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

sevlet-context.xml:

```
<annotation-driven/>

<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
<beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>

<beans:bean id="tilesConfigurer"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="definitions">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles/admin.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="tilesViewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="viewClass">
        <beans:value>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView
        </beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="order" value="0"/>
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.bookstore.controllers"/>
```

In jsp I use many combinations href:

```
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/AdminLTE-2.3.0/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
href="/resources/AdminLTE-2.3.0/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"
href="app-name/resources/AdminLTE-2.3.0/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

but css not load. What could be the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For spring to be able to identify which resources are jsp/tiles or static like CSS and JS, you need to add a `resourceHandler`:

In XML this looks like:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

The issue you might have is that you did not define the namespace in your resource mapping.

Answer (score 0):

When using tiles best practices suggest that static files should be reachable using the apache tiles engine as well

To do so in your jsp template add at the beginning of the file the following

```
<tiles:importAttribute name="stylesheets" />
```

then in the header add

```
<header>
        <!-- stylesheets top -->
        <c:forEach var="css" items="${stylesheets}">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="${css}"/>">
        </c:forEach>
</header>
```

This will inject all the css defined in your definitions at the beginning of the jsp page

Then if you want to add a new css file go in the admin.xml file and do something like below

```
<definition name="home" extends="app.base">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Home Page" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/home.jsp" />
    <put-list-attribute name="stylesheets" inherit="true">
        <add-attribute value="/resources/AdminLTE-2.3.0/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </put-list-attribute>   
</definition>
```

Of course the resorces must be server correctly as mentioned by @Norbert

Also if you are using tiles 3 please check if the configuration is as below:

```
<bean id="tilesViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver">
</bean>
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/admin.xm</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for tips. I solved the problem in two ways:
Change in `web.xml`:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

or add:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The problem also makes web browser which kept the old things in the cache.